# How to scroll top of the page when button click in visual force page?

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I have created a visual force page.when i click button at the bottom of the page,its should scroll to top of the page because i am showing an error at the top of the page when field is empty.anybody help on this....
thankyou

Answer (score 3):

You should add `oncomplete="window.scrollTo(0,0);"` to your button/link like

```
<apex:commandButton value="Top" oncomplete="window.scrollTo(0,0);"/>
<input type="button" value="Top" oncomplete="window.scrollTo(0,0);">
```

If you have associated an action to the button, it will execute and then goes to top of the screen.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i am not using apex:commandbutton. i am using input type="button"

Comment: You can use oncomplete with HTML input button as well. See my updated answer.

Comment: i had used oncomplete but its not working.my div have overflow-y:auto

Comment: <input type="button" class="buttonstyles" name="inputbutton" value="save" onclick="buttonaction()" oncomplete="window.scrollTo(0,0);"  />    <div id="testdiv" style="overflow-y:auto"></div>.i need to go starting of the div.